# Rails - Get the Days from 2 Datestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datestamp

I've two datestamps:

**18 Nov 2013**

**21 Nov 2013**

How can I take the day's between these two datestamps?

The final result should look like:

**Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday**

**Edit:**

Thanks @Alok Swain

now i want to print the days on the page... but it prints me the array out without giving him the command to do that :/

output:

```
["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday" ]
```

and when i make a foreach loop it prints me only the days (that is what i want)

but with the array, too :D

output:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday


["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday" ]
```

**EDIT**

Resovled: I had in the view:

`<%= @foo.each do |f| %>`

instead:

`<% @foo.each do |f|%>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
start_day = Time.parse("18 Nov 2013").wday # gives 1 (Monday)
end_day = Time.parse("21 Nov 2013").wday # gives 4 (Thursday)

days_arr = %w(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday)
days = []
for i in start_day..end_day
  days << days_arr[i]
end
```

Comment: This code does not work when the weekday number of `end_day` is smaller than `start_day`.